# setup pycharm IDE for Qgis plugin Development

Tags: python, plugins, qgis, snap

I'm using PyCharm as the IDE, Qgis"3.30" integrated python"3.9" and snap "Sentinel Application platform" software which provides a python package. my problem is setup IDE for qgis plugin development